# How to pre-fill a text box on a website in a WKWebView using swift

Tags: html, swift, xcode

I'm relatively new to coding and extremely new to using swift. I'm trying to create something where my users can set a user name and password in settings and have that information pre-fill the login page of a WKWebView I have set up. Currently I'm just trying to test getting the swift code to send the information over to the text field.

I couldn't find much information on this other then one or two stack posts from a few years ago but they didn't seem to work for me.

According to what I've read, I need to get some Javascript to execute to fill in the areas but nothing I'm doing seems to be working. I'll post the small bit of testing code I'm using in swift. If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or if I'm just missing something obvious it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: WKWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL (string: "https://www.google.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        WebView.load(request)

    }


    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: WKWebView!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('q').value = 'Hello' ;")
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend you can use like this ,

```
//   let source = "document.body.style.background = \"#777\";"

        let source = "document.getElementById('q').value = 'Hello' ;"
        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)

        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.userContentController = userContentController
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
        view.addSubview(webView)
        let url = URL (string: "https://www.google.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
```

[as Apple said](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller) , A WKUserContentController object provides a way for JavaScript to post messages and inject user scripts to a web view.

Comment: oh wait never mind, I got it to work with other websites but for what ever reason it just didn't want to work with google. Thank you!

Comment: Im not sure if you're still checking this thread or not but is there any specific reason you did this with a subview? Can it be done without? @dengApro

Comment: No subview. The only difference between is that you use storyboard, I use code to create the WKWebView.